# datetime string and unix datetime into readable common format?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have `visit_date_time` column which contains datetime in strings as well unix format together, I want it to convert it into a common datetime format for further feature engineering. How can I do it so in Python?

```
6587980    2018-05-20 14:19:55.951
6587981    2018-05-24 15:53:26.731
6587982    2018-05-27 07:55:17.768
6587983    2018-05-25 11:28:56.526
6587984    2018-05-10 12:23:21.786
6587985    2018-05-07 10:08:08.978
6587986    2018-05-11 20:50:38.239
6587987    2018-05-21 10:21:37.663
6587988        1526139196864000000
6587989    2018-05-07 14:49:23.292
6587990    2018-05-14 21:18:43.132
6587991    2018-05-07 10:36:55.887
6587992    2018-05-09 05:42:04.907
6587993    2018-05-22 09:05:42.329
6587994                        NaN
6587995    2018-05-21 07:14:03.231
6587996    2018-05-25 09:13:04.011
6587997                        NaN
6587998    2018-05-20 12:09:35.347
6587999    2018-05-17 03:30:22.330
```

I have bold type the 3 different types in the same column.

Comment: Are you asking about R or Python?

Comment: @mkrieger1 In Python

Comment: Then please don't add the R tag.

Comment: Which value do you want to get as result for the NaN input?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I want back it as NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using `dput` to provide a sample of your data.

You can use the pacakge `lubridate` and `dplyr` to have a common format for all your dates:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
data <- data %>%
    mutate(visit_date_time = as_datetime(visit_date_time))
```

The function `as_datetime` automatically convert UNIX to understandable format.

Edit: This is a **R** answer

Comment: No, sorry, I'm not an expert at all in python

Answer (score 0):

for an example

```
df
         v                        t
0  6587987  2018-05-21 10:21:37.663
1  6587988      1526139196864000000
2  6587989  2018-05-07 14:49:23.292
3  6587990  2018-05-14 21:18:43.132
4  6587991  2018-05-07 10:36:55.887
5  6587992  2018-05-09 05:42:04.907
6  6587993  2018-05-22 09:05:42.329
7  6587994                      NaN
8  6587995  2018-05-21 07:14:03.231
```

we can use a 2-step approach; parse datetime strings first, then the numbers:

```
# 1) parse strings to datetime
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'], errors='coerce')

# 2) where we have numeric values
m = pd.to_numeric(df['t'], errors='coerce').notnull()
# parse these to datetime as well; Unix time nanoseconds is default (otherwise, set unit kwarg)
df.loc[m, 'datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['t'][m].astype('int64'))
```

to get

```
df
         v                        t                datetime
0  6587987  2018-05-21 10:21:37.663 2018-05-21 10:21:37.663
1  6587988      1526139196864000000 2018-05-12 15:33:16.864
2  6587989  2018-05-07 14:49:23.292 2018-05-07 14:49:23.292
3  6587990  2018-05-14 21:18:43.132 2018-05-14 21:18:43.132
4  6587991  2018-05-07 10:36:55.887 2018-05-07 10:36:55.887
5  6587992  2018-05-09 05:42:04.907 2018-05-09 05:42:04.907
6  6587993  2018-05-22 09:05:42.329 2018-05-22 09:05:42.329
7  6587994                      NaN                     NaT
8  6587995  2018-05-21 07:14:03.231 2018-05-21 07:14:03.231
```

Answer (score -2):

import datetime

s = 1526139196864000000

fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S:%m"

s = float(s)/1000000

t_utc = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(s/1000)

print(t_utc.strftime(fmt))

Comment: I don't think this addresses the question - which is about how to handle a mix of date/time string, Unix time nanoseconds and NaNs. Besides, please give some explanation as well, not just code as an answer.